# Tranformar array em matriz unica

Tags: php

Bom dia,

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade, atualmente meu array retorna da seguinte forma:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Vermelho"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Azul"
  }
}
```

O exemplo acima está ruim de trabalhar, pois um array está aparentemente dentro de outro. Gostaria que o retorno fosse algo como:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Vermelho"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Morango"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Maça"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Amora"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "Amarelo"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "Banana"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "Damasco"
}
```

Como trabalho com um array para que ele fica da forma acima e não 1 array dentro do outro?

Comment: Como é que é que você está montando o primeiro array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você puder garantir que todos os itens dentro do `array` possua sempre outro `array`com o campo `name`, basta usar o `array_map`.

```
$lista = array_map(function ($item) {
       return $item['nome'];
}, $array);
```

A função `array_map` retorna um `array` formatado de acordo com o que é retornado no seu `callback`. No caso acima, usamos o `callback` para retornar apenas o valor presente em `'name'`

Comment: Não funcionou aqui